# FloatingActionButton onpressed() not working in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

when i click the fab theres nothin happen 
here's my code maybe one of you guys can help :)

```
void initSpeechRecognizer(){
    _speechRecognition = SpeechRecognition
FloatingActionButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.mic),
                    onPressed: (){
                      if(_isAvailable && !_isListening) _speechRecognition.listen(locale: "id_ID").then((result) => print('result : $result'));
                    },
                     heroTag: "mic",
                  ),
```

Comment: here's my full code https://github.com/lutfiadysh/build.gradle/blob/master/flutter

Comment: Any error? or something. Try checking the value of `_isAvailable` and `_isListening` before using the if statement

Comment: my app run normally but when i click the button theres nothing happen

Comment: try printing the value of _isAvailable and _isListening

Comment: how to do that im new in flutter guide me please :))

Comment: print(_isAvailable); inside your onPressed method @LutfiArdiansyah

Comment: the app still show nothing i think the button is not working.

Comment: @LutfiArdiansyah put a debug breakpoint in onPressed. It's a small red dot and usually on the left, behind the line number. This way you can see if you are hitting those code lines or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this;

```
void initSpeechRecognizer(){
    _speechRecognition = SpeechRecognition
FloatingActionButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.mic),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if(_isAvailable && !_isListening){
                          var result = await _speechRecognition.listen(locale: "id_ID");
                          print('result : $result');
                      }
                    },
                     heroTag: "mic",
                  ),
```

Comment: still the same, any action i can do ?

Comment: I look your full code but you don't call this function "initSpeechRecognizer()" 

you can change like this;

`@override 
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
initSpeechRecognizer();
  } `